# The type Stack is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Character>

Tags: java, generics, collections, stack

I am trying to write a simple program to use stacks.It is giving me the error

> The type Stack is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

```
import java.util.*;

    public class Stack {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<> ();
                s.push("Hello");
                System.out.println(s);

            }

        }
```

Comment: How do i fix the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class `Stack` is shadowing `java.util.Stack`. You could rename your class, or use the fully qualified class name like

```
java.util.Stack<Character> stack = new java.util.Stack<> ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can `import java.util.Stack` with the other imports to avoid such type of error.

Answer (score 0):

Here the name of the class given by you is the same as that of **java.util.Stack** so the compiler is getting confused and using Stack(as a class). In order to overcome this challenge you either need to follow one of the given 2 Solutions :
1. Change the name of your class to be different other than **Stack**
2. When declaring Stack declare it using **java.util.Stack**